# Bounty expiration email is wrong for bounties on others' questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounty, email

I recently put a bounty on [Running QuickCheck properties in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37219533/running-quickcheck-properties-in-parallel), which was asked by another user. The bounty expired and there are no answers. I got an email notifying me of this including the text

> Thanks for putting a bounty on your question. It looks like there are
>   still no answers yet. You should consider improving your question to
>   attract more answers. Could you:
>
> - add more text describing the problem?
> - add or change the tags?
> - update the title to more accurately reflect the issue?

Well, *maybe*, but not really. Aside from the fact that the question is fine it's **not my question**. The text in such a case should really reflect that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're absolutely right. The code and text there is biased from the days when only the post owner could start a bounty - which hasn't been the case for quite some time. Any future emails (after the next build) will be sensitive to whether you (the bounty owner) are also the post owner or not.